# How to place woocommerce order with meta_data with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, native

i am creating a resturant delivery react native app using woocommerce api and trying to place an order with Woocommerce API using axios.

on the website, i can select a product, its optional dishes and place the order. and it creates successfully..

but in the app i do like this.

```
{
  payment_method: "cod",
  payment_method_title: "Cash On Delivery",
  set_paid: true,
  billing: {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
    address_1: "969 Market",
    address_2: "",
    city: "San Francisco",
    state: "CA",
    postcode: "94103",
    country: "US",
    email: "john.doe@example.com",
    phone: "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  shipping: {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
    address_1: "969 Market",
    address_2: "",
    city: "San Francisco",
    state: "CA",
    postcode: "94103",
    country: "US"
  },
  line_items: [
    {
      product_id: 1479,
      quantity: 2
    },
   
  ],
  shipping_lines: [
    {
      method_id: "flat_rate",
      method_title: "Flat Rate",
      total: "10.00"
    }
  ]
};
```

it creates the order successfully but only shows the side items without calculating the price. means only the basic price is shown on the order without adding the additional products.

Comment: Please share  your  code  this information is not sufficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.